# Rename folders in file share

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The script is comparing folder names in a share where we store user profiles to those in AD and seeing which ones are disabled or don't exist and counting them. I now want to take that list and rename all the user folders that aren't in AD to `.old`.

```psh
$delusercount = 0
$usernotfoundcount = 0
$foldernames = (Get-ChildItem \\kiewitplaza\vdi\appsense_profiles).Name

foreach($name in $foldernames)
{
    try
    {
       $user = get-aduser $name -properties enabled
       if($user.enabled -eq $false)
       {
          $delusercount = $delusercount + 1
       }
    }
    catch
    {
        $usernotfoundcount = $usernotfoundcount + 1
    }
}  

write-host "User disabled in AD count " $delusercount
write-host "User ID NotFound in AD count " $usernotfoundcount
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just after:

```
$delusercount = $delusercount + 1
```

Insert:

```
rename-item "\\kiewitplaza\vdi\appsense_profiles\$name" `
            "\\kiewitplaza\vdi\appsense_profiles\$name.old"
```

#### *Update:*

You probably also want to insert just after your `foreach` statement:

```
if($name.EndsWith(".old"))
{
    continue
}
```

This will prevent previously renamed folders from being processed and renamed again thus ending up for example with the folder for user `Bob` becoming `Bob.old` then potentially `Bob.old.old` then `Bob.old.old.old` and so on.